# Sanity Check - Significant increase in the number of objects when using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, refactoring

I am using JUnit for the first time in a project and I'm fascinated by the way it is forcing me to restructure my code. One thing I've noticed is that the number of objects I've created in order to be able to test chunks of code is significantly increasing. Is this typical?

Comment: What is "significant" increase? In my experience, you create one JUnit class for each "payload" class, i.e. foo.java <-> fooTest.java. The number of methods in ...Test may be quite substantial but that depends on how scrupulous you wanna be.

Comment: Are you talking about test classes, or about additional classes and objects in your normal code?

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example where this has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this is normal.**

In general the smaller/more focused your classes and methods are, the easier to understand and test them. This might produce more files and actual lines of code, but it is because you are adding more abstractions that makes your code have a better/cleaner design.

You may want to read about the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Uncle Bob also has some re-factoring examples in his book called [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) where he touches on exactly these points.

One more thing when you are unit testing. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is one of the single most important thing that will save you a lot of headaches when it comes to structuring your code. (*And just for clarification, DI will not necessary cause you to have more classes, but it will help decouple your classes more from each other.*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is fairly typical. When I start introducing testing code into a legacy codebase, I find myself creating smaller utility classes and pojos and testing those. The original class just becomes a wrapper to call these smaller classes.

One example would be when you have a method which does a calculation, updates an object and then saves to a database.

```
public void calculateAndUpdate(Thing t) {
  calculate(t); // quite a complex calculation with mutliple results & updates t
  dao.save(t);
}
```

You could create a calculation object which is returned by the calculate method. The method then updates the Thing object and saves it.

```
public void calculateAndUpdate(Thing t) {
  Calculation calculation = new Calculator().calculate(t); // does not update t at all
  update(t, calculation); // updates t with the result of calculation
  dao.save(t); // saves t to the database
}
```

So I've introduced two new objects, a Calculator & Calculation. This allows me to test the result of the calculation without having to have a database available. I can also unit test the update method as well. It's also more functional, which I like :-)

If I continued to test with the original method, then I would have to unit test the calculation udpate and save as one item. Which isn't nice.

For me, the second is a better code design, better separation of concerns, smaller classes, more easily tested. But the number of small classes goes up. But the overall complexity goes down.

Comment: Why isn't your Calculator static? .calculate(t). And why do you have to have Calculation? Could you just pass the actual result of the calculation, whatever it would be to the update method instead of wrapping it in the Calculation object?

Comment: It could be static, I could combine the three lines into one, but it's just an example. The original calculate() method does the calculation (which can have multiple results) *and* updates the Thing object, the point is to dissociate the two methods. In the case where you have multiple results, you'll need an intermediate class. The above is just an illustration of the general technique.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what kind of objects you are referring to. Typically, you should be fine with using a mocking framework like EasyMock or Mockito in which case the number of additional classes required solely for testing purposes should be pretty less. If you are referring to additional objects in your main source code, may be unit testing is helping you refactor your code to make it more readable and reusable, which is a good idea anyways IMHO :-)